# How to prove the implication $(\neg q \rightarrow (\neg p \lor \neg q))$?

Tags: solution-verification, proof-writing, proof-explanation

I am working on a proof for the statement:

Suppose $x, y \in \mathbb{R}$. If $5|x$ and $5|y$, then $5|xy$

Let's denote the propositions as follows:

- $P: 5|x$
- $R: 5|y$
- $Q: 5|xy$

Logically, this is represented as $(P \land R) \rightarrow Q$.

Now, I am aiming to conduct a contrapositive proof, transforming my proposition into $\neg Q \rightarrow \neg (P \land R)$, and applying Morgan's laws, I get $\neg Q \rightarrow (\neg P \lor \neg R)$.

Here's my question: Do I need to prove that $(\neg P)$ is true OR $(\neg Q)$ is true? Or do I have to prove both $(\neg P)$ is true AND $(\neg Q)$ is true simultaneously?

I am inclined to think that proving either $(\neg P)$ or $(\neg Q)$ is sufficient,because otherwise there would not be any logical distinction between $(\neg Q \rightarrow (\neg P \lor \neg Q))$ and $(\neg Q \rightarrow (\neg P \land \neg Q))$. I want to ensure I am on the right track.

Comment: Adopting the contrapositive: "Do I need to prove that (¬) is true OR (¬) is true?" - YES. Either (or both) being true suffices to make the statement hold.

Answer (score 0):

Remember that you don't actually know that $(P \land R) \implies Q$. That implication is the statement you are trying to prove. Then, after the rearranging, what you *want to prove* is $\neg Q \implies (\neg P) \lor (\neg R)$. That is, if we *assume* $\neg Q$, we want to show that this implies either $\neg P$ or $\neg R$. In the context of your proof, this means that if we assume $5 \nmid xy$, we want to show that $5 \nmid x$.

I don't know if the contrapositive is required for the particular exercise you're doing, but the proof can also be done without it - start with the fact that for $x \in \mathbb{N}$, if $5 \mid x$, then $x = 5k$ for $k \in \mathbb{N}$.